# Significance of Shree Satyanarayan Puja

Tags: vedas, vishnu, puranas, puja, vishnu-purana

[Shree Satyanarayan Pooja](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALiCzsZ3woTKaHrpTLQrpVnJ6W24ZmLNJQ:1666670154079&q=shree%20satyanarayan%20pooja&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjehfeTvvr6AhWN8HMBHTlaC-QQ0pQJegQIBRAB)

What is the significance of Shree Satyanarayan Puja?

What are the different rituals in the Puja?